# Using apply and abind with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

I am using **`apply`** and **`abind`** to create a dataframe with the average of all the individual values from three similar data frames. I want to loop this code where the only thing that changes is the name of the instrument I am using (CAI.600, Thermo.1, etc).

This is what I have so far:

```
FIDs <- c('CAI.600', 'Thermo.1')

for (Instrument in FIDs) {
  A.avg <- apply(abind::abind(paste0('FID.Eval.A.1.', Instrument), 
                              paste0('FID.Eval.A.2.', Instrument),
                              paste0('FID.Eval.A.3.', Instrument),
                              along = 3), 1:2, mean) 
  assign(paste0('FID.Eval.A.', Instrument), A.avg)
  }
```

where all the df's look similar to this (same number of rows and columns):

```
> FID.Eval.A.1.CAI.600
   FTIR    O2  H2O CAI.600 CAI.600.bias
1 84.98 20.90 0.06  254.96         0.01
2 49.98 20.90 0.09  150.09         0.09
3 25.00 20.94 0.09   75.24         0.31
4 85.03 10.00 0.08  251.99        -1.22
5 50.03 10.00 0.09  148.51        -1.06
6 24.99 10.00 0.07   74.00        -1.27
7 84.99  0.10 0.06  246.99        -3.13
8 50.03  0.10 0.14  146.50        -2.39
9 24.96  0.10 0.10   72.97        -2.55

 > FID.Eval.A.2.CAI.600
   FTIR    O2  H2O CAI.600 CAI.600.bias
1 85.45 21.37 0.53  255.43         0.48
2 50.45 21.37 0.56  150.56         0.56
3 25.47 21.41 0.56   75.71         0.78
4 85.50 10.47 0.55  252.46        -0.75
5 50.50 10.47 0.56  148.98        -0.59
6 25.46 10.47 0.54   74.47        -0.80
7 85.46  0.57 0.53  247.46        -2.66
8 50.50  0.57 0.61  146.97        -1.92
9 25.43  0.57 0.57   73.44        -2.08

> FID.Eval.A.3.CAI.600
   FTIR    O2  H2O CAI.600 CAI.600.bias
1 85.32 21.24 0.40  255.30         0.35
2 50.32 21.24 0.43  150.43         0.43
3 25.34 21.28 0.43   75.58         0.65
4 85.37 10.34 0.42  252.33        -0.88
5 50.37 10.34 0.43  148.85        -0.72
6 25.33 10.34 0.41   74.34        -0.93
7 85.33  0.44 0.40  247.33        -2.79
8 50.37  0.44 0.48  146.84        -2.05
9 25.30  0.44 0.44   73.31        -2.21
```

I ether get an error message stating "along must be between 0 and 2", or when I adjust along I get a warning stating "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA".

Should I be using something other than for loop.

When I run **`abind`** without using **`for loop`**, the end result looks like this:

```
## Average of repeat tests
FID.Eval.A.CAI.600 <- apply(abind::abind(FID.Eval.A.1.CAI.600, 
                                         FID.Eval.A.2.CAI.600, 
                                         FID.Eval.A.3.CAI.600,
                                         along = 3), 1:2, mean) 
FID.Eval.A.CAI.600 <- as.data.frame(FID.Eval.A.CAI.600)

> FID.Eval.A.CAI.600
   FTIR    O2  H2O CAI.600 CAI.600.bias
1 85.25 21.17 0.33  255.23         0.28
2 50.25 21.17 0.36  150.36         0.36
3 25.27 21.21 0.36   75.51         0.58
4 85.30 10.27 0.35  252.26        -0.95
5 50.30 10.27 0.36  148.78        -0.79
6 25.26 10.27 0.34   74.27        -1.00
7 85.26  0.37 0.33  247.26        -2.86
8 50.30  0.37 0.41  146.77        -2.12
9 25.23  0.37 0.37   73.24        -2.28
```

Where 'FID.Eval.A.CAI.600' displays the average for each value from the three df's.

Comment: I added the desired result data frame as well additional sample data.  Is there another function that would give me the same results?  I can't seem to find anything aside from abind that gives me the same values. Also, abind() seems to work great since I can also use it to get the SD for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix immediate problem, use `get()` to return object by character reference. As of now, your `paste0` calls will only return character strings and not actual object.

```
abind::abind(get(paste0('FID.Eval.A.1.', Instrument), envir=.GlobalEnv), 
             get(paste0('FID.Eval.A.2.', Instrument), envir=.GlobalEnv),
             get(paste0('FID.Eval.A.3.', Instrument), envir=.GlobalEnv),
             along = 3)
```

In fact, for a more dynamic solution consider `mget` to return all objects by name pattern without hard-coding each of the three objects.

Also, in R it best to avoid use of `assign` as much as possible. Instead, consider building **one** list of *many* objects with functional assignment and avoid flooding global environment with many separate objects. Below iterates using `sapply` to build a *named* list of average matrices.

```
FIDs <- c('CAI.600', 'Thermo.1')

mat_list <- sapply(FIDs, function(Instrument) {        
    FIDs_list <- mget(ls(pattern=Instrument, envir=.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv)
    FIDs_arry <- do.call(abind::abind, c(FIDs_list, along=length(FIDs_list))) 

    return(apply(FIDS_arry, 1:2, mean))
}, simplify = FALSE)

# OUTPUT ITEMS
mat_list$CAI.600
mat_list$Thermo.1
```

Even update names to conform to your original needs.

```
names(mat_list) <- paste0("FID.Eval.A.", names(mat_list))

mat_list$FID.Eval.A.CAI.600
mat_list$FID.Eval.A.Thermo.1
```

Comment: I am having issues with the sapply() function.  When I run it the way you have it written, I get an error for unexpected comma after "mean)" and unexpected parenthesis after "FALSE".  If I remove these, I get the same error I got with my for loop: "along must be between 0 and 2".

Comment: See edited text and code. `simplify=FALSE` should be outside the curly brace as last arg of `sapply`. And `get` is needed. But even `mget` can be used.

Comment: I'm assuming there should be an additional ')' at the end of the line with FIDs_list? When I run the code with the parenthesis, I still get an error: "Error in arg.list[[1]] : subscript out of bounds".

Comment: See edited code. Correct on closing parenthesis and we need to add `.GlobalEnv` for `ls`, `get`, and `mget` calls since environment changes within a function. Without searching top level global environment, these function returns nothing.